# Deciding what type of model to use for predicting the bottom decile of student grades

Tags: neural-network, classification, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I have a large dataset which includes 36 variables (in %iles) to describe a student, and then the output is the students grades as a %ile. I am trying to predict, using the 36 variables, whether a student will fail out, ie. be in the bottom 2%ile.

My first attempt was a neural network with binary classification, forcing the model to predict that the student is either in the bottom 2%ile, or not. Having read a few posts on FHarrell.com, I was thinking that a binary logistic regression that outputs the probability of being in the bottom percentiles is better?

Or alternatively, should I just do a non-binary linear regression to directly predict the students %ile? The reason I thought that this wouldn't be as useful for my purposes is because I don't care about making predictions between any of the other percentiles. For example, I don't care about distinguishing between an A and a B student, I am just looking to identify F students. Therefore I would be losing accuracy in the bottom 2%ile and gaining it in the other irrelevant %iles?

Finally, I think that the neural network makes sense given that there is interaction between the variables. But if there is another model that I should consider please let me know.

Comment: Be cautious with premature dichotomization - by doing so, you're implicitly telling the algorithm that there is no difference between an A student and a D- student, and that both are equally distinct from an F student.

Answer (score 1):

> My first attempt was a neural network with binary classification,
>   forcing the model to predict that the student is either in the bottom
>   2%ile, or not. Having read a few posts on FHarrell.com, I was thinking
>   that a logistic regression that outputs the probability of being in
>   the bottom percentiles is better?

I would recommend you start with logistic regression as a baseline. Then when you have your baseline I would compare the LR-model with a tree-based ensemble since they tend to work really well on tabular data. I would recommend [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), it is easy to work with and is not that prone to overfitting. Then if you are feeling fancy you could try gradient boosting with [XGBoost](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [LGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). They tend to give marginally better results, but takes some more effort to work with.

> Or alternatively, should I just do a non-binary linear regression to
>   directly predict the students %ile? The reason I thought that this
>   wouldn't be as useful for my purposes is because I don't care about
>   making predictions between any of the other percentiles. For example,
>   I don't care about distinguishing between an A and a B student, I am
>   just looking to identify F students. Therefore I would be losing
>   accuracy in the bottom 2%ile and gaining it in the other irrelevant
>   %iles?

I agree.

> Finally, I think that the neural network makes sense given that there
>   is interaction between the variables.

Neural networks are generally not that good on tabular data. Unbalanced, which your have with a ration of 1:50, is especially hard for NNs. Then they tend to classify everything as the majority class.

Comment: OK thank you very much and just to clarify, when you say "I agree."  you think that I am correct? That a linear regression would lose accuracy where I want it and hence is not a good idea?

Comment: Sorry and one more question, do you recommend a random forest regressor or random forest classifier?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am agreeing with. Do binary classification because it is more in line with your objective.

Comment: I also strongly recommend to use PCA, if you use logistic regression. Due to the fact that, there are many variables of student are irrelevant to the percentiles e. g., length , and hair color. I worked with logistic regression a week ago with tabular data containing 60 columns (5 columns after using PCA) , **the training accuracy was 84% without PCA, 97% with PCA and tuning some parameters** such as batch size and random_state. Please don't forget to standardize the data before the PCA.